# str_replace not replacing a url extracted from a database

Tags: php, str-replace

I am trying to extract a filepath of an image from a MySQL database and turn it into a URL. However when I pass it through str_replace no changes are been made. I have set up a test document with a path preset and it works without any problems.

My code that extracts the path from the database is

```
$user_image = get_web_path($row['user_pic_path']);
```

where

```
function get_web_path($file_system_path) {
   return str_replace(var_dump($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']), '', var_dump($file_system_path));
}
```

editted

```
My test code is:

<?php
   echo "DOCUMENT_ROOT: {$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']}";
   $image_sample_path = "C:/wamp/www/website/images/image123.jpg";
   $web_image_path = str_replace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], '', $image_sample_path);

   echo "<br /><br />CONVERTED PATH: {$web_image_path}";
?>
```

Which outputs:

```
   /website/images/image123.jpg"
```

However when extracting the value from the database, C:/wamp/www from the 'user_pic_path' field isn't being replaced.

var_dump('DOCUMENT_ROOT') gives

```
string 'C:/wamp/www' (length=11)
```

var_dump($file_system_path)) gives

```
string 'C:/wamp/www/website/images/image123.jpg' (length=39)
```

Comment: can you give a few image paths, and what $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] is so if the answer @anubhava gave doesn't work we have more insight to help you resolve the problem.

Comment: can you echo/var_dump $user_image variable and see what you get. May be you are not getting correct value from your database query itself ? The function seems to be working fine though.

Comment: Why do you store absolute paths in the database in the first place? Looks like the path stored in the database doesn't match to me, so check that value. But you should nevertheless switch to relative paths for your assets…

Answer (score 1):

Why do you have curly braces around `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` ?

Try replacing that with:

```
str_replace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], '', $file_system_path);
```

Comment: Still not working even without curly brackets. I will post my test code with set values to show that it works that way.

Comment: it looks ugly but there is nothing wrong with that the OP is doing

Comment: I agree with Orangepill. I tried that function on my system and it is working as it is.

Comment: Please provide var_dump output of `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` and  `$file_system_path`

Comment: Please add `var_dump($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);` and `var_dump($file_system_path);` inside the `get_web_path` function and show us the output.